# SyncAdapter: setDeviceApps ERROR

Tags: android

I have got this error in logcat file multiple times in a row, what is it?
Is it a problem in my code?!

```
E/SyncAdapter: setDeviceApps ERROR <html>
    <head><title>503 Service Temporarily Unavailable</title></head>
    <body bgcolor="white">
    <center><h1>503 Service Temporarily Unavailable</h1></center>
    <hr><center>nginx/1.10.0 (Ubuntu)</center>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Your app can't connect to Nginx, the web server... Not an issue in your code

Comment: I don't have any Nginx web server, I use firebase and fabric for analytics, is it possible that my app cant connect to one of the tow?

Comment: How do you know this error comes from **your** app? If you use Firebase, you wouldn't have a syncadapter

Comment: I filtered the log data by my app in logcat.

Comment: Okay, then edit your question to add the syncadapter code

Comment: I don't have any syncadapter code, I see this error in my logcat file sometimes. I searched this error and cant find anything. I am in iran and because of the upcoming election some sites are filtered by ... (Just some sites is not filtered) like Fabric. (I don't see any log in fabric, just a few) I think maybe one of library that I used in my app cant connect to the server (own server) Firebase of Fabric.